# How to disable permission requests on Android 12?

Tags: android, android-permissions, administrator

I am developing an app for an Android platform (OS 12). This application will not have a screen, will not be deployed on the Google PlayStore and will have access to different media (camera, storage, ...).

Since I won't have a screen, I'd like to know how to disable permission requests, knowing that my `targetSdkVersion` should stay at `30`.
Is there a way to have "all rights" on the app?

Comment: "This application will not have a user interface" -- unless you are building your own custom firmware, what will allow this application code to run? "I'd like to know how to disable permission requests" -- unless you are building your own custom firmware, this is not an option.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry by "user interface" I meant no screen. This application will only use a camera. Are you saying that the only way to disable permission requests is to modify my Android BSP to bypass these requests?

Comment: "I meant no screen" -- understood, but something needs to run that code. "Are you saying that the only way to disable permission requests is to modify my Android BSP to bypass these requests?" -- I am saying that a pre-installed app can be pre-granted permissions (though I do not know exactly how you do that), but a user-installed app has to go through the permissions UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may enforce permissions without asking the user if you first declare what apps and which permissions the system should whitelist.

You can read more about it here:
https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/perms-allowlist

Comment: Indeed, I managed to "bypass" these permissions by following your link, thanks!
However, there are still two dialogs that are problematic after that: allowing access to a USB device and confirming Wi-Fi connection to an access point.
It looks like we need to modify the Android source code for this (already done for USB and it works).